# Fragment WebView should load last URL

Tags: android, url, webview, save, fragment

In my application I have a sliding menu, In sliding menu I have four options, those are fruits, vegetables,animals, birds. And these are fragments. In each fragment I have a Web view. now what I want is when I am loading a web and performed some search , now I will open another fragment and would like to perform another search. it is going good . but what I want is if I am performing some search then it has to save the last URL which I have visited. I am able to save last URL in single web but unable to do in multiple fragments.
here is my code in which I can save last URL with single class.

```
 public class SearchFragment extends Fragment {
 WebView wv;
 private ProgressBar bar;
 private String url="http://www.google.com";

 public SearchFragment(){}

 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, 
     false); 

    wv = (WebView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.search_web);
    bar = (ProgressBar)rootView.findViewById(R.id.search_bar);
    bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    loadUrl();
    return rootView;
 }


private void loadUrl() {
    WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
    /* below function saved the password in WebView */
    webSettings.setSavePassword(true);

    wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
            if (progress == 100) {
                bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                wv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

        }
    });
    wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                String description, String failingUrl) {
            //Toast.makeText(CommunityFragment.this, description, 
   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), description, 
  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    wv.loadUrl(url);
  }

   // flipscreen not loading again
   @Override
            public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
  }

  // Handling BackPress events
  public void onBackPressed() {
    if (wv.canGoBack()) {
        wv.goBack();
    } else {
        getActivity().finish();
    }
  }
 }
```